# How can i get the value from the selected list in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

Example,

```
<div>
    <ul class="menu" id="list">
        <li>
            <a>list 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>list 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>list 3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>list 4</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>list 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>            
</div>
```

What i want is, if the user clicks on of the list

i want to get the value(list 1,2,3,4....)

How can i get this?

i googled a little and make like this.

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    alert($('#list li a').html());
})
```

it only shows list 1, not others :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).find('a').html());
});
```

Comment: aha! this was the thing!

Comment: the only problem is, it has some blank spaces. how can i trim?

Comment: Glad it helped you :) $(this) refers to the object(in context) which has triggered the click event.

Answer (score 2):

Try simply

```
 $('#list li').click(function(){
               alert($(this).text());
            })
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1452/)

Comment: nope not working. Doesn't this ':selected', only works in select box?

Answer (score 0):

Use `this`

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    alert($('a',this).html());
});
```

Demo `------>` http://jsfiddle.net/W88R5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
  window.alert($('a', this).html());
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/wnPWB/1)